# Elastic search - Spring boot: None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: tomcat, elasticsearch, jhipster

I am deploying my monolithic JHipster application to Tomcat. I have installed elastic search as a service in order to use it as a seperate node with my application. 
Elastic search is working fine (localhost:9200 returns the cluster info).

I added this config to my application-prod.yml

```
  data:
    elasticsearch:
        cluster-name: elasticsearch
        cluster-nodes: localhost:9300
        properties:
            http:
                enabled: true
```

When I start tomcat I get this error :

```
   .AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you trying to use?

Comment: Also, where are you deploying Tomcat?  Locally or on something like AWS?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I was using the wrong version of elasticSearch.

According to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix), I have to use a version between 2 and 5 since I am working with spring boot 1.5.